# Residue fields of infinite product of finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ be the finite field of order $p^n$. Is it possible to choose an infinite set $S\subseteq \mathbb {N}$ such that all residue fields of $A:=\prod_{n\in S}\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are finite?

Comment: Yes: if $\omega$ is any nonprincipal ultrafilter supported on the set of factorials $\{k!:k\ge 1\}$, then any ultraproduct $\prod^\omega F_{p^n}$ contains the algebraic closure of $F_p$.

Comment: Can you please tell me a refernce?

Comment: This follows from Los's theorem: the point is that any particular polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{k!}}$ for all but finitely many values of $k$, which implies by Los's theorem that it has a root in the ultraproduct.

Comment: In general, is it possible to choose an infinite subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that all residue fields of $A:=\prod_{n\in S}\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are finite?

Comment: If $S$ is, say, the set of prime numbers, any residue field will have the property that the set of algebraic elements over $F_p$ is finite (and reduced to $F_p$). But I guess that residue fields, apart from obvious projections, are always uncountable.

Comment: and it's at least clear that if $K_n$ are fields of cardinal tending to infinity, then any quotient field of $A=\prod K_n$ that is not a projection is infinite. Indeed, let $F$ be a finite quotient field, $p$ its char; so we can suppose all $K_n$ also of char $p$. Let $P$ be a nonzero polynomial in $F_p$ vanishing on $F$. Then $P(A)$ is in the kernel $I$ of $A\to F$. for large $n$, $P(K_n)$ is nonzero, hence generates $K_n$ as an ideal. So $I$ contains $K_n$ for all large $n$. Thus $F$ is given by some projection. (If we refer to ultraproducts, it's also clear by Los' theorem)

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty: you have not just edited the question, you have changed it completely. Readers may have trouble understanding the answers now.

Comment: I hadn't noted that the question has changed. My previous comment proves that the answer to the new question (at this very time: find $S$ such that all residue fields are finite) is: no.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And sorry for the radical changes made in the question. I was not sure whether to put it as a new question. I sincerely apologize for the possible inconveniences it may have caused to the readers.